# Karate-config.js failed and js failed

Tags: javascript, java, maven, karate

I use Java 17 and I upgrade karate to version to 1.4.0 and Junit5 to version 1.4.1.RC2 I can`t run my tests.
Tests works in 0.9.6 version of Karate and old version Junit but no in latest version.

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>csr-web-karate-tests</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <properties>
        <karate.version>1.4.0</karate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pl.santander</groupId>
            <artifactId>informix-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.vitaliy</groupId>
            <artifactId>mazovia-charset</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${karate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RC2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
            <artifactId>js</artifactId>
            <version>23.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
            <artifactId>js-scriptengine</artifactId>
            <version>23.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My runner class

```
public class WipTest {
    @Karate.Test
    Karate wipTest() {
        return Karate
                .run("classpath:features")
                .tags("@wip")
                .relativeTo(getClass());
    }
}
```

And My karate-config

```
function fn() {
    var env = karate.env;
    var baseUrl = '';
    var secondUrl = '';
    var accessToken = '';
    var accessToken1 = '';
    var datebase = '';

    if (env === "dev") {
        var port = 8080;
        baseUrl = 'http://localhost' + ":" + port + "/api";

    } else if (env === "RELEASE") {
        baseUrl = "hidden specially";
        accessToken = getZt2Token();
        secondUrl = 'hidden specially';
        accessToken1 = getRelease();

    } else if (env === "ZT002") {
        baseUrl = "hidden specially";
        accessToken = getZt2Token();
        secondUrl = 'hidden specially';
        accessToken1 = getRelease();

    } else if (env === "ZT004") {
        baseUrl = "hidden specially";
        accessToken = getZt4Token();

    } else if (env === "ZT001") {
        baseUrl = "hidden specially";
        accessToken = getZt1Token();

    } else {
        baseUrl = null
        secondUrl = null
        accessToken = null
        accessToken1 = null
        datebase = null
    }

    var config = {
        env: env,
        address: baseUrl,
        address1: secondUrl,
        accessToken: accessToken,
        accessToken1: accessToken1,
        datebase: datebase,
    }

    karate.configure('connectTimeout', 30000);
    karate.configure('readTimeout', 60000);

    return config;
}

function getRelease(){
    var config = {};
    var tokenUrl = 'hidden specially';
    var grantType = 'hidden specially';
    var clientSecret = 'hidden specially';
    var clientId = 'hidden specially';
    config.authInfo = {
        authTokenUrl: tokenUrl,
        authClientId: clientId,
        authClientSecret: clientSecret,
        authGrantType: grantType,
    }
    var result = karate.call("classpath:src/test/java/features/getAccessToken.feature", config)['response'];
    return result['access_token'];
}

function getZt2Token() {
    var config = {};
    var tokenUrl = 'hidden specially';
    var grantType = 'hidden specially';
    var clientSecret = 'hidden specially';
    var clientId = 'hidden specially';
    config.authInfo = {
        authTokenUrl: tokenUrl,
        authClientId: clientId,
        authClientSecret: clientSecret,
        authGrantType: grantType,
    }
    var result = karate.call("classpath:src/test/java/features/getAccessToken.feature", config)['response'];
    return result['access_token'];
}

ect.
```

And my test

```
Scenario Outline: PUT Transaction - accept -  <decision>, <reasonId>, <comment>
    * url address1
    * path 'hidden specially'
    * header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + accessToken1
    * configure ssl = true
    * def req = read('classpath:src/test/java/resources/transaction.json')
    * def randomPaymentId = call read('classpath:src/test/java/resources/randomPaymentId.js')
    * set req.header.paymentId = randomPaymentId

    Given request req
    When method POST
    Then status 200

rest hidden specially
```

Test are good but no matter what you do I have this error:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: >> classpath:features/acceptOrBlockTransactionsNegative.feature:185
>> karate-config.js failed
>> js failed:
>>>>
next is the complete karate-config
```

Anyone know what this might be about? I read all stackoverflow and I don`t find a solution.

Comment: the JS engine is stricter. try making `karate-config.js` a single function and the other 2 helper functions within it or move them out read from separate files. that is all that can be diagnosed remotely. if you still are stuck, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - in future ask your team to try the RC releases as soon as they are available to avoid surprises and provide feedback. you are attempting a huge jump in version so you will have problems.

Comment: ok I am one step forward but still can`t call karate-config.js
When I write url is working but wchen I want use address1 in karate-config.js is not working.
Authorization: Bearer accessToken1 --> in here must be a token not variable

Comment: sorry, I give up

Comment: quickly :P I must find why :D